# error: something went wrong while testing postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, postman

am getting an error while testing api via postman error are like "something went wrong"

**authRoute.js**

This is the authRoute where I wrote my whole application logic and please tell me how to fix my error and also i attach dbErrorHandling.js file where i handle my error

```
const User = require('../models/userModel');
const expressJwt = require('express-jwt');
const _ = require('lodash');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const {OAuth2Client} = require('google-auth-library');
const {validationResult} = require('express-validator');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
//custome error handler to get useful error from the dataase error
const {errorHandler} = require("./helpers/dbErrorHandling");
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.MAIL_KEY)

exports.authRoute = (req,res)=>{
   const {name,email,password} = req.body;
   const errors = validationResult(req);
   if(!errors.isEmpty()){
      const firstError = errors.array().map(error=> error.msg[0])
      return res.status(422).json({
            error:firstError
      })
   }
   else{
      User.findOne({
         email
      }).exec((err,user)=>{
         //if user exists
         if(user){
            return res.status(400).json({
               error:"Email is taken"
            })
         }
      })
      //genrate token

      const token = jwt.sign(
         {
            name,email,password
         },
         process.env.SECRET,
         {
            expiresIn:'15m'
         }
      )
      //email data sending
      const emailData = {
         from : process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
         to:'harsalpatil512@gmail.com',
         subject: "account activation link",
         html:`
         <h1>Please Click link to activate</h1>
         <p>${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/user/activate/${token}</p>
         <hr/>
         <p>This email contain sensitive info</p>
         <p>${process.env.CLIENT_URL}</p>`
      }

      sgMail.send(emailData).then(sent=>{
         return res.json({
            message: `Email has been sent to ${email}`
         })
      })
      .catch(err=>{
         return res.status(400).json({
            error: errorHandler(err)
         })
      })
   }
}
```

**dbErrorHandling.js**

This is an errorhandling file where i got error don't know where am wrong

```
"use strict"

/*

Get Unique error field name

*/

const uniqueMessage = error => {
    let output;
    try {
        let fieldName = error.message.split('$')[1]
        field = field.split('dub key')[0]
        filed = field.subString(0, field.lastIndexOf("_"))
        req.flash('errors', [{
            message: "An account with" + field + "already exists"
        }])

        output = fieldName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + fieldName.slice(1) + "already exists"
    }
    catch (err) {
        output = "already existes"
    }
    return output
}

/*
Get the error meassage from error object
*/

exports.errorHandler = error => {
    let message = ""
    if (error.code) {
        switch (error.code) {
            case 11000:
            case 11001:
                message = uniqueMessage(error)
                break;
            default:
                message = "something went wrong"
        }
    } else {
        for (let errorName in error.errors) {
            if (error.errors[errorName].message) {
                message = error.errors[errorName].message
            }
        }
    }
    return message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want use your approach use .status(200) for `res` like this:

```
sgMail.send(emailData).then(sent=>{
  return res.status(200).json({
     message: `Email has been sent to ${email}`
  })
})
```

and use console.log(err) in `.catch` block to showing real error

but I prefer using async/await with try/catch because it's cleaner like this:

```
const User = require('../models/userModel');
const expressJwt = require('express-jwt');
const _ = require('lodash');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const {OAuth2Client} = require('google-auth-library');
const {validationResult} = require('express-validator');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
//custome error handler to get useful error from the dataase error
const {errorHandler} = require("./helpers/dbErrorHandling");
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.MAIL_KEY)

exports.authRoute = async (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password } = req.body;
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  try {
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      const firstError = errors.array().map((error) => error.msg[0]);
      return res.status(422).json({
        error: firstError,
      });
    } else {
      let user = await User.findOne({ email });
      if (user) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          error: "Email is taken",
        });
      }
      //genrate token

      const token = jwt.sign(
        {
          name,
          email,
          password,
        },
        process.env.SECRET,
        {
          expiresIn: "15m",
        }
      );
      //email data sending
      const emailData = {
        from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
        to: "harsalpatil512@gmail.com",
        subject: "account activation link",
        html: `
         <h1>Please Click link to activate</h1>
         <p>${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/user/activate/${token}</p>
         <hr/>
         <p>This email contain sensitive info</p>
         <p>${process.env.CLIENT_URL}</p>`,
      };
      try {
        await sgMail.send(emailData);
        return res.status(200).json({
          message: `Email has been sent to ${email}`,
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("sgMail Error : ", error);
        if (error.response) {
          console.error(error.response.body);
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Main Error : ", error);
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: errorHandler(error),
    });
  }
};
```